# how to pass Project ID to another component in react.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

**Hello Guys, i create a table in MyProjectList.js file for displaying project data now i want, If user Click on table row then i want to pass this clicked Project Id to Collection.js file to use in query to compare.

*this is MyProjectList.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const pageSize = 10;
export default function MyProjectsList() {

  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState();
  const [paginatedProject, setPaginatedProject] = useState();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const userState = useSelector(state=> state.loginUserReducer)
  const {currentUser} =userState;

  const coordinatorId = currentUser.id;

  useEffect(() => {
   axios.post("http://localhost:4000/coordinatorsProjects",
   {
     coordinatorId : coordinatorId
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data,'==>>> this is coordinator projects');
      setProjects(res.data);
      setPaginatedProject(_(res.data).slice(0).take(pageSize).value());
    });
  }, [coordinatorId]);

  const pageCount = projects ? Math.ceil(projects.length / pageSize) : 0;
  const pages = _.range(1, pageCount + 1);

  const pagination = (pageNo) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNo);
    const startIndex = (pageNo - 1) * pageSize;
    const paginatedProject = _(projects)
      .slice(startIndex)
      .take(pageSize)
      .value();
    setPaginatedProject(paginatedProject);
  };


//***using this function i am nevigate user to colletion.js component. how to pass project id this?

  const onRowClick = async (e) =>  {
   navigate("/coordinators/collection")
   console.log(e)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        {/* {loading && (<Loading/>)} */}
        {/* {error && alert("Error occured to get data")} */}
        {!paginatedProject ? (
          "ERROR: Data Not Found. Please check your internet connection!"
        ) : (
          <Table className="table table-hover table-light  table-bordered shadow">
            <thead className="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Project Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Budget Rs.</th>
                <th scope="col">Remaining Rs.</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {paginatedProject.map((user, _id) => (
                <tr onClick={ onRowClick } key={_id}>
                  <td>{user.projectName}</td>
                  <td>{user.startDate}</td>
                  <td>{user.endDate}</td>
                  <td>{user.budget}</td>
                  <td>{user.remaining}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        )}

        <nav className="d-flex pagination justify-content-center ">
          <ul className="pagination ">
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <li
                className={
                  page === currentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item"
                }
              >
                <p className="page-link" onClick={() => pagination(page)}>
                  {page}
                </p>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

*this is Collection.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash";

const pageSize= 10;

export default function Collection () {
  const [donors, setDonors] = useState()
  const [paginatedDonors, setPaginatedDonors] = useState()
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/coordinatorsCollection",
    {
      projectID : "7"
     }).then((res)=>{

    console.log(res.data);
    setDonors(res.data);
    setPaginatedDonors(_(res.data).slice(0).take(pageSize).value());
   
  }); 
  }, []);

  const pageCount= donors? Math.ceil(donors.length/pageSize) :0;
  const pages = _.range(1, pageCount+1)

  const pagination= (pageNo) =>{
    setCurrentPage(pageNo)
    const startIndex = (pageNo -1) * pageSize;
    const paginatedDonors = _(donors).slice(startIndex).take(pageSize).value();
    setPaginatedDonors(paginatedDonors)
  }

    return (
        <>
      <div className='container'>
      <h3 align="center">Collection of users</h3>
     {/* {loading && (<Loading/>)} */}
     {/* {error && alert("Error occured to get data")} */}
     {!paginatedDonors ? ("ERROR: Data Not Found. Please check your internet connection!"):(
        <Table className="table table-hover table-light  table-bordered shadow">
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>        
              <th scope="col">Donor Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Contact No</th>
              <th scope="col">Amount</th>
              <th scope="col">Project</th>
              <th scope="col">Project Budget</th>
              <th scope="col">Donate Date.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody >
      
              {paginatedDonors.map((donors, id) => (
                  <tr key={id}>
                      
                      <td>{donors.name}</td>
                      <td>{donors.mobileNo}</td>
                      <td>{donors.amount}</td>
                      <td>{donors.project}</td>
                      <td>{donors.projectBudget}</td>
                      <td>{donors.donateDate}</td>
                   
                  </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        )}

 <nav  className="d-flex pagination justify-content-center ">
  <ul className="pagination ">
  
    {
      pages.map((page)=>(
        <li className={
          page === currentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item"
        }>
          <p className="page-link"
          onClick={()=>pagination(page)}
          >{page}</p></li>
      ) )
    }
  </ul>
</nav>
          </div> 
        </>
    )
};
```

**temporarily i am sending '7' (hard coded) to the api to check and it working fine. But i want clicked project id in this.**

thank you!!!

Comment: I think you should have a store like `Redux` or `Context` to save clicked `Project Id` and in other component to listen it. You can also save `id` in `localStorage` or in `sessionsStorage` or in `IndexedDB` if it is safe to you and then just get this `id`

Comment: yes, i have but i use redux to store  users login data

Comment: That is greate. Just create an `Action` and `Reducer` to store `Project Id` and listen it everywhere :)

Comment: so if i store project id in localStorage how rows to know which one clicked and what this particular projects id?

Comment: Action onClick: `localStorage.setItem('projectId', projectId);`
And then get value like this `localStorage.getItem('projectId');`

Comment: i do like this, i m setItem project id when click on row but it set all projects id after click i want only 1 row's project id that clicked.

Comment: It looks like you have problem with click event target. Use `console.log` or `debugger` in your `clickHandler` function to see what was in the `event.target` and in `event.currentTarget`

Comment: this is my onclick() funtion inside i m sending all ids:- const onRowClick = async (e, row) =>  {
    localStorage.setItem('projects',JSON.stringify(projects.map((data)=>(data.id))));
    console.log(e,"<<<<= testing In onRow click.....")
    navigate("/coordinators/collection")
  }

Comment: You need only 1 `id`. You can get this `id` when you mapping projects `paginatedProject.map((user, _id)`. Just get `projectid` from `user` and in `onClick` write this: `{(e) => onRowClick(e, user.projectId)}`

Comment: thank you so much @EzioMercer i'll got this in onClick() function 
 i had to do like this:- {(e) => onRowClick(e, user.id)}

Comment: I'm very glad to hear it. If it is not difficult for you can you please accept my answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one `id`. You can get this `id` when you mapping projects in `MyProjectList.js` file at this line `paginatedProject.map((user, _id) => ()`.

Just get `projectid` from user and then send it into `onClick` like this:

```js
onCLick = {(e) => onRowClick(e, user.projectId)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use react context for this situation because your issue is the meaning of using react context; React context is a general state that you can set or edit or use your general state in all your components easily

Comment: how can i do this????

Comment: Read this document it will help you https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html